# Django Test Suite URL Coverage

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I'd like to make sure that my Django test suite covers all URLs listed in my URL configuration. Is there a way to compare the list in the URL configuration to a list of URLs that have been hit during a test suite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to come up with a solution by defining a custom test suite runner that records the URLs being accessed and compares it to the list of configured URLs.

Here's the code: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2694/

Answer (score 0):

You should use django-coverage

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-coverage

It runs your test suite, and outputs nice html reports of what code is covered. I think this will be a more fail-safe and robust way to make sure that all your urls are covered.

Comment: I am already using this, but I also want URL coverage, since you could cover all code paths without covering all URLs.