# test that an URL is matching the correct view

Tags: django, django-urls, django-testing

for these two django url patterns

`(r'^articles/(\d{4})/$', 'news.views.year_archive'),` 
`(r'^articles/2003/$', 'news.views.special_case_2003'),`

the `special_case_2003` view will never be called because of the wider pattern above it

how can i test (in tests.py) what view have been matched via an URL pattern to be sure my urls are matching the desired views

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This won't let you match the raw regular expression, but it'll let you match an example of a pattern:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve

def test_foo(self):
    func = resolve('/foo/').func
    func_name = '{}.{}'.format(func.__module__, func.__name__)
    self.assertEquals('your.module.view_name' func_name)
```

Answer (score -1):

You should put the special case first:

```
(r'^articles/2003/$', 'news.views.special_case_2003'),
(r'^articles/(\d{4})/$', 'news.views.year_archive'),
```

The urls are evaluated from top to bottom thus rendering the first view for which an url matches. You can just test these urls by using them in your browser or you could write a specific test for them in tests.py.

For more information on how to test urls.py read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/testing/#testing-tools which explains both how you can check whether you get a 200 response and how you can test whether certain content is present.

Here is the canonical example:

```
>>> from django.test.client import Client
>>> c = Client()
>>> response = c.post('/login/', {'username': 'john', 'password': 'smith'})
>>> response.status_code
200
>>> response = c.get('/customer/details/')
>>> response.content
'<!DOCTYPE html...'
```

Comment: yes the special case should be first,
but many cases you are extending third party apps and conflicts may happen
I want to write a specific test for them in tests.py and the question is HOW?

Comment: Hi MYaser. Did you get to read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial05/?

Comment: yes I did, but nothing there for testing the url matching
you can test the context, templates, ... but at last you could not know explicitly what view has been executed

Comment: you could read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9403194/django-test-suite-url-coverage and check selenium (for instance, http://benlopatin.com/2012/django-selenium-testing/)