# After running unittests, I want to see all the requests Django has processed

Tags: python, django, nose, django-nose

My Django project has ~300 unit tests.  I want to see all the URLs (and HTTP methods - GET/POST/etc) that have been used in the course of unit testing.

The end goal is to produce two (nose) coverage reports:

- coverage of all the URLS defined in the various urls.py files
- coverage of my Swagger API

Before I go digging into the Django source code, I'm wondering if anyone knows if this is already done for free by some Django object, or if not, a good hint at where to start prodding around.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9403194/django-test-suite-url-coverage This helps?

Comment: Thank you for this.  I ended up creating a Django Middleware class, much in the same style as shown here: https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2694/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [django-request](https://github.com/kylef/django-request). Maybe it can solve your problem.